# How do I make the action sheet make the surrounding view darker when it's called?

Tags: ios, ipad, modal-dialog, uiactionsheet

The action sheet naturally greys out the background view a little bit, but it isn't really noticeable. I want to make it much darker.

Also, how do I make it so you cannot click anywhere else? Right now if you click outside of the action sheet, it makes the action sheet go away. I want that to not happen - you should have to push the "cancel" button to make the action sheet go away.

Comment: You need to create your own if you want different behavior.

Comment: Your second requirement goes against Apple's guidelines. Tapping outside the action sheet (on an iPad) is meant to be treated like Cancel.

Comment: ah thanks, you saved me a lot of time attempting to make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *shadowView; 

- (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet
{
    if (!self.shadowView)
    {
        self.shadowView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
        self.shadowView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(42.0/255.0) green:(42.0/255.0) blue:(42.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];
        self.shadowView.alpha = 0.7;
        [self.view addSubview:self.shadowView];
    }
    else
    {
        self.shadowView.alpha = 0.7;
    }
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    self.shadowView.alpha = 0.0;
}
```

Comment: This gives me the error - Property 'shadowView' not found on object of type 'testProjectViewController'

Comment: Hello, McFly? Look at my answer, it includes the property :)

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget, if you want to animate the alpha in and out, you can use basic UIView block based animations :) Happy coding!